# Is there a service to upload images and metadata to?

Tags: images, api, metadata, uploader

We're looking for a software that allows applications to communicate with one of our webservers in order to store images.

These requirements are a must:

- available as FOSS
- receives an image along metadata

  - e.g. the latter in headers of a POST request
  - or as multipart body
- validates image format and integrity
- validates the metadata against a schema
- stores the image in a specified collection
- updates an accompanying METS/MODS-file
- authentication

  - preferably with JWT
- authorization on collection-level

It would be a plus if these requirements were met:

- further management operations via a ReST-API

  - renaming, deleting of files incl. necessary metadata updates
  - collections management
- a web interface

Is there a software that meets these requirements or offers enough leverage to build a solution upon it?